# Can we simply change/rearrange the order of navigation?

Tags: navigation

Can we simply change/rearrange the order of navigation?[image]

My manager asked me to bring the "Jobs" to the top part, instead of "Newsfeed". Because he said according to data analytics, more user is looking for the "Jobs".

Is this the right way? Is it will affect the user experience?

Answer (score 2):

**How much it affects the experience depends on how regularly your users visit the site**

New users won't notice, frequent visitors will have to relearn it, but even if your users visit daily, swapping a couple of menu labels isn't going to cause too much confusion. The risk here is low.

If you start renaming items, then yes, that has a much bigger potential for error and confusion, and you should test any changes with representative users before launching.

Comment: Thanks. I agreed with you "How much it affects the experience depends on how regularly your users visit the site" 

But in this situation, I was thinking about the Jacob’s law - users prefer our site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know - such as Facebook, Linkedin, Quora etc...The news feed is always on top. Now it's at the bottom, is it will bring the bad ux? 

Besides that, if we found less user is using the newsfeed, should we focus on how to improve the newsfeed to bring more engagement? instead of rearranging the order?

Answer (score 2):

Frequent reordering is not useful because of user habits. Data should be read carefully instead of a blind decision. 'Too many people click on Jobs, then let's carry it on top' approach cannot always a good thing. It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

For example, imagine that your website's primary focus is messaging, message button isn't clicked too much. People love learning section of your application, and it's clicking rate is much higher than the message. What will you do? Data says learning section is important, but your company wants to sail with the messaging feature. You probably heard the Henry Foard saying: 'If I had asked people what they wanted, they would have said faster horses.'

So don't make rash decisions, investigate data carefully.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple version of menu optimisation. Basically you have some metrics saying there will be a benefit for users by moving an option further up a menu - this is totally fine and if it is indeed based on solid pre-analysis then there is little to no risk here.

If you have real concerns and want to prove this indefinably you can always A/B test the position of this to see whether moving it up the list is having a positive or negative effect. Further still, you may want to look at new vs repeat visitors to see which is better for each group of users.

Answer (score 0):

Sclarke is correct. You have metrics and you can make a scientific guess that moving the Jobs nav to the top won't cause too much harm. I can't see the data, but I'm hoping the drop rate isn't high on the Jobs tab.

If more evidence is needed, then I'd suggest to conduct card sorting from your users.